# How to inject commands via SSH in python?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Using paramiko is not possible for this.

---

This is for a python program being ran on a linux OS.
Using the following method I can successfully ssh into another card on my shelf.

```
def ssh(self, target_arg):
        cmd = self.get_command_output(subprocess.Popen(["ssh", target_arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE))
        return cmd.communicate()[0]
```

However I have an array of commands to be executed on the secure shell :

```
commands = ["cd somepath/file/examplefilepath","./examplebashscript"]
```

which I want to execute chronologically on the card I have ssh'd into from my python program:

```
def ssh_with_commands(self, target_arg, commands):
        self.ssh(target_arg)
        for command in commands:
            # execute command on target shelf shell
```

and then carry on running the rest of the python program on the original thread.

---

Any solution on how I either pipe these commands to ssh or what the solution might be?

sincerely a python and linux newb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands have to be passed to `ssh` itself; `self.ssh(...)` doesn't return until you exit the remote shell. This will require modifying `ssh`.

```
def ssh(self, target_arg, commands=None):
        cmd_args = ["ssh", target_arg]
        if commands is not None:
            cmd_args.append(";".join(commands))
        output = self.get_command_output(subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE))
        return cmd.communicate()[0]
```

Note this has some significant drawbacks regarding quoting; you are probably better off using a library like Paramiko to open a connection and send the commands one at a time.

Comment: Thanks just testing this out now, realised too in above code output should be replaced by "cmd"

Answer (score 1):

SSH already allows running a command instead of a shell.

> NAME
>        ssh -- OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface] [-b bind_address]
>            [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file]
>            [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
>            [-J destination] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
>            [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
>            [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination
>            [command]

Thus, a simpler solution presents itself: place the commands you wish to run inside a single script file on your server. And then simply run your ssh command like so:

```
ssh <server> ./script.sh
```

This example assumes that your script file is located in the home directory of the user you are logging in as. Otherwise, just specify the full path to the file.